# how to make bookmark sidebar like microsoft edge in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am using google chrome as my default browser but I like a bookmark of Microsoft edge which opens from the sidebar.

how can I do the same in chrome because chrome shows bookmark bar beneath `search bar`

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of that bookmark sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I have done some research on google I found there is no setting for bookmark sidebar that in `google chrome` then I go for an alternative and i found some app in `chrome web store`

1. [Bookmark Sidebar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-sidebar/jdbnofccmhefkmjbkkdkfiicjkgofkdh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
2. [Candy Bookmarks Sidebar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/candy-bookmarks-sidebar/ecihdamikhodclcebamgjmlhoinmalah?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Answer (score 0):

In Edge I can do: Ctrl+Shift+O -> type -> hit Enter

I have some short bookmark names to let me navigate quickly without touching mouse.

In Chrome I hit: Ctrl+Shift+O -> wait till new tab opens -> type -> ... and I need to click on a result.

I found this [Bookmark Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-search/hhmokalkpaiacdofbcddkogifepbaijk) plugin solving the problem. I need to go to the search bar and then: type "bm" -> Tab -> type -> hit Enter.

Not bad but still I like the Edge better (I'm using different browsers at work).